# Insert or update bulk records

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

How can I update or insert bulk operations in Meteor Mongodb?

Here is my simple script:

```
var obj = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
    obj.push({title: i, inTime: new Date(), outTime: new Date})
}

Activities.bulkWrite([
    { 
        insertMany: obj 
    }
])
```

Why I am getting this error:

**`Exception while invoking method TypeError: Activities.bulkWrite is not a function`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor Collection object doesn't have the bulkWrite function. Remember, Meteor uses a lib to provide MongoDB function. To access the native functions of MongoDB in a collection, you need to use `rawCollection`. See [here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-rawCollection).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what is **Activities** is referred to here.
If Activities is the schema or collection object, then just use as `Activities.insertMany` function to insert all the records to your database collection.

Hope this helps!!!